# How do correctly add a getter to a Vuex Module?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to create a Vuex module whenever I register the module, I get a state is undefined, even though there is nothing calling the getter I had just made. I'm able to call actions correctly with no errors.

This is my module. `customer.js`

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,

    state: {
        login: false,
    },

    getters: {
        isLoggedIn: (state) => {
            console.log(state);
            state.login;
        }
    },

    mutations: {
        set_login: (state, login) => {
            state.login = login;
        },

        set_orders: (state, orders) => {
            state.orders = orders;
        },

    },

    actions: {
        newsletter_subscribe: (context, email) => {
            //- TODO 
        },
    }
}
```

I have register via the registerModule function.

```
import Customer from './customer';
store.registerModule('customer', Customer, {
    preserveState: true
});
```

Whenever I have developer tools open it just alerts me that. 
Uncaught ReferenceError: state is not defined
    at isLoggedIn (customer.js:11)
    at wrappedGetter (vuex.esm.js:734)

Am I doing anything wrong with my getter?

I've only noticed the getter being called with Vue Dev tools open as I tried putting an alert in the getter to see what else could be triggering without the state being passed in.

Comment: Try not to export it as `default`. Don't know if `namespaced: true`(https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing) might not like it.

Comment: What other way would you recommend? I'm using name spacing so I can have the ease of doing `Store.dispatch('customer/newsletter_subscribe',true);` It works with actions, not mutations and getters. I am also using namespaces as further modules will need to applied to the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by giving my store a blank state!

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {}
});
```

And registering modules as normal.